# Splitting string into substrings of different lengths in R

Tags: r, string

I have read similar subjects, but my substrings has different lengths (9,3,5 characters each) and for that have not found any answer.

I need to split 17 characters long string into three substrings where first one has the length of 9, next length of 3, the last the length of 5 characters.

Example:

```
 N12345671004UN005
 N34567892902UN002
```

I would like to split strings into three columns:

First col 9 char.length

```
"N12345671"      
"N34567892"
```

Second col 3 char.length

```
"004"          
"902"
```

Third col 5 char.length

```
"UN005"  
"UN002"
```

Comment: `?substr` will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
instr = c("N12345671004UN005", "N34567892902UN002")
out1 = substr(instr, 1, 9)
out2 = substr(instr, 10, 12)
out3 = substr(instr, 13, 17)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try `read.fwf` and specify the `widths`

```
ff <- tempfile()
cat(file=ff, instr, sep='\n')
read.fwf(ff, widths=c(9,3,5), colClasses=rep('character', 3))
#        V1  V2    V3
#1 N12345671 004 UN005
#2 N34567892 902 UN002
```

Or using `tidyr/dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
as.data.frame(instr) %>%
       extract(instr, into=paste0('V', 1:3), '(.{9})(.{3})(.{5})')
#         V1  V2    V3
#1 N12345671 004 UN005
#2 N34567892 902 UN002
```

Or a combination of `sub` and `read.table`

```
read.table(text=sub('(.{9})(.{3})(.{5})', '\\1 \\2 \\3', instr),
              colClasses=rep('character', 3))
#         V1  V2    V3
#1 N12345671 004 UN005 
#2 N34567892 902 UN002
```

#### data

```
instr = c("N12345671004UN005", "N34567892902UN002")
```